# Visual basic how to check a string is in the english dictionary

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm writing a Hangman game on visual basic as a school project. I want the program to be able pick any word from the English dictionary for the player to guess. I was wondering if there was a simpler way than having a massive list of words for the program to pick from?

thanks

Comment: Please be more specific of your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't a simpler way; either you keep a list yourself, or you use a web service that can provide what you want.

If you want your own list, you can get a text file with 479K words from GitHub here: https://github.com/dwyl/english-words

An example of a web service that can provide a random word is Wordnik https://www.wordnik.com/ who provide an API.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you I will have a look at that!